# Is there a way to let python detect alphabetical characters and produce an error message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

tkinter/python newbie here. I built a calculator using tkinter and I can't seem to find any way to allow python to detect alphabetical characters entered into the entry widget. My goal is to let it detect the alphabetical characters and display an error message.

Heres my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
#Title of the Window(s)
root.title("Jeff's Geometry Calculator")

#Fonts for this project
LARGEFONT = ("Verdana", 35)
BUTTONFONT = ("Times", 15)
ANSWERFONT = ("Courier", 25, "bold")
ANSWERLABELFONT = ("Courier", 25)
DESCRIPTIONFONT = ("Verdana", 18)
DESCRIPTIONFONT1 = ("Verdana", 12)

descriptionLabel = Label(root, text="Cube Volume Calculator", font=LARGEFONT, padx=50, pady=50)
descriptionLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

equationLabel = Label(root, text="Cube Volume Equation: l³", font=DESCRIPTIONFONT)
equationLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)

equationLabel1 = Label(root, text="Note: l = length", font=DESCRIPTIONFONT1)
equationLabel1.grid(row=2, column=0)

numEntry = Entry(root, width=10)
numEntry.grid(row=3, column=0)

def cubeVolumeAnswer():
  cubeNum = (numEntry.get())
  result = float(cubeNum) * float(cubeNum) * float(cubeNum)
  answerLabel.config(text=str(result))

myButton = Button(root, text="Calculate", font=BUTTONFONT, command=cubeVolumeAnswer, padx=50, pady=50)
myButton.grid(row=4, column=0)

number = str(numEntry.get())

answerLabel = Label(root, text="", font=ANSWERFONT)
answerLabel.grid(row=6, column=0)

answerLabel1 = Label(root, text="Answer: ", font=ANSWERLABELFONT)
answerLabel1.grid(row=5, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you get your number by numEntry.get()? You could always write a simple for loop to iterate over the string and test if alphabetical characters are present with `character.isalpha()`.

Comment: @Amey Vijeesh has the correct answer. Also instead of multiplying `float(cubeNum)`  3 times, you can use  `float(cubeNum)**3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a try/except statement, basically, try will attempt to preform the task but in case of error, instead of an intimidating error message in the console, it will execute the except block:

```
try:
    print(1 + z)
except:
    print("invalid equation")
```

in your case you can simply:

```
def cubeVolumeAnswer():
    cubeNum = (numEntry.get())
    try:
        result = float(cubeNum) * float(cubeNum) * float(cubeNum)
    except:
        result = "invalid equation"
    answerLabel.config(text=str(result))
```